# python error NameError: name 'ofclass' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have an task to do to figure out what the code below does. it looks like it was constructed in python2 but I want to use python3. I have installed argparse which it requires and set up necessary file path but every time I run the program in command Line I get these issues.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\pythonScripts\Noddy.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Noddy:
  File "C:\Users\Name\pythonScripts\Noddy.py", line 63, in Noddy
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "C:\Users\Name\pythonScripts\Noddy.py", line 57, in main
    ent = Noddy.make(fools)
NameError: name 'Noddy' is not defined
```

The code is below.

```
#! python3


class Noddy:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.ant = None
        self.dec = None
        self.holder = x

    @classmethod
    def make(self, l):
        ent = Noddy(l.pop(0))
        for x in l:
            ent.scrobble(x)
        return ent

    def scrobble(self, x):
        if self.holder > x:
            if self.ant is None:
                self.ant = Noddy(x)
            else:
                self.ant.scrobble(x)
        else:
            if self.dec is None:
                self.dec = Noddy(x)
            else:
                self.dec.scrobble(x)

    def bubble(self):
        if self.ant:
            for x in self.ant.bubble():
                yield x
            yield self.holder
            if self.dec:
                for x in self.dec.bubble():
                    yield x

    def bobble(self):
        yield self.holder
        if self.ant:
            for x in self.ant.bobble():
                yield x
        if self.dec:
            for x in self.dec.bobble():
                yield x

    def main():
        import argparse
        ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        ap.add_argument("foo")
        args = ap.parse_args()

        foo = open(args.foo)
        fools = [int(bar) for bar in foo]
        ent = Noddy.make(fools)

        print(list(ent.bubble()))
        print
        print(list(ent.bobble()))

    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Have you included the entire error? I just see a stacktrace?

Comment: Using @classmethod with self makes it error. Use cls instead.

Comment: update with full error

Comment: Your indentation now makes no sense. My guess is that your `main` and `if __name__=='__main__'` stuff is all inside your class. But unless you accurately show your indentation, it's hard to tell.

Comment: This is how it looks on my side now. Indentation is fixed.

Comment: @BenWells Indentation is definitely _not_ fixed. If this the actual indentation of your code, running it would immediately give an `IndentationError`.

Comment: Also, the title has to be updated when we find the solution because it does not provide any information for anyone looking to solve the same error.

Comment: Now I can see your indentation, it's possible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `def main()` and `if __name__=='__main__'` have been written *inside* your class. The interpreter tries to execute them while it is defining the class, and can't, because the class `Noddy` doesn't exist until the class definition is finished.

Fix the indentation so that the `main` stuff lies *outside* your class.

```
class Noddy:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.ant = None
        self.dec = None
        self.holder = x
    # other methods INSIDE the class
    # ...

# Notice the indentation — this function is OUTSIDE the class
def main():
    # whatever main is supposed to do
    # ...

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```